# Can't change the screenshot directory because "com.apple.screencapture: command not found"

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, screen-capture

I used to be able to change the screenshot directory by just changing the location and typing in the specifics to the terminal but now I am getting this code and I have no idea what to do.

I went through everything a month ago to manually erase everything because my Mac was running slow. I think I might have accidentally deleted something I needed. What should I do? My desktop is getting extremely cluttered. I am using a MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ ChristianJ$ 
MacBook-Pro:~ ChristianJ$ com.apple.screencapture location /Users/mac/Documents/Zoology/edited\ screen\ shots
-bash: com.apple.screencapture: command not found
MacBook-Pro:~ ChristianJ$
```

Comment: Isn't `defaults write` missing ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102452/can-i-undo-changes-made-via-defaults-write

Answer (score 10):

The error message is telling you that the shell (bash) is expecting the first expression on the command line to be a program, script, or shell built-in. `com.apple.screencapture` is none of those.

The command you are missing is `defaults`, with a sub-command of `write`, like so:

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/mac/Documents/Zoology/edited\ screen\ shots`